# Get selected text select2 using javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, select2-rails

I have a select2 input field which successfully i can get all my data but i want to get the test of d selected data from the dropdown list

This is my select2 input field

```
<%= f.input_field :lender_id, collection: Lender.all.pluck(:code, :id), id: 'lender_field_code', name: 'lender_field_code', class: 'form-control legal-service lender_field_code', prompt: 'Please Select Banker', disabled: (f.object.new_record? ? false : true ) %>
```

and in my javascript file i have this

```
var str1= $('.lender_field_code').select2("data").text();
 console.log(str1);
```

when i select any data it returns all d data in my select2 not what i selected. how do i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( ".lender_field_code" ).change(function() {
            alert( $(this).find("option:selected").text() );
        });
    });
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: This code is not working.....Please have a look into this http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/1220/

Comment: The first snippet definitely shouldn't work (`select2('data')` returns an object) but the second might work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".lender_field_code").select2()
.on("change", function(e) {
   $("#select_val").html(e.val);
})
```

Please have a look into this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/1218/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too
On `change` event of select with id `lender_field_code`, get the `selected` item and read it's val with `.val()`

```
$('.lender_field_code').change(function() {   
    $('#select_val').append($('.lender_field_code :selected').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While all the above mentioned solutions work,  I didn't wanted to use `on Change` event and then I noticed that

```
var text = $('.lender_field_code').select2("data").text();`
```

returns the selected item plus whatever comes after it as array like, so I used the below solution

```
 var text = $('.lender_field_code').select2("data")[0].text();
```

index[0] is the selected item

and if you want the value, well you don't need  `on change` even,
[Select2 JS](https://select2.org/)  directly sets the `.val()` attribute, you can get it on the fly like this

```
var value= $('.lender_field_code').val();
```

and if you have multiple `selects` that use the `Select2`, then you must specifiy your target with unique name, id, class, etc. or loop through them.